# Needing advice with "strict mime" settings on Wordpress with a geo mapping app that predates my employment

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, mime-types, geocoding

Refused to execute script from '...blah/blah/airspace.json' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

It says that its mime type is ('application/json') but its actually type='text/javascript'; The problem is I did try and change the type to 'application/json' and it stopped working on VS Code- I am using Google maps javascript api and the geo coder.

The format seems weird for the JSON files as well because even though they are saved as .json, they are formatted as a javascript file- Some how this works though?

The airspace.json file on my vs code editor, comes back with this error:
Expected a JSON object, array or literal.

I have another json file set up the same way....its a javascript file saved as .json file-

var psgodmc = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features":[....info....]},

Because this was on word press (not by my choice) I did add various mime exceptions to the application from FTP and the WP Add Mime plug-in application gui. I was expecting this to work, it worked on the application with no errors, that I have a static copy of, but it didn't work on word press-

(((RESOLVED...Thanks Berrie))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wordpress side have you tried including `application/json` from Mime types.
Add this to your themes `function.php`

```
function my_custom_mime_types( $mimes ) {
     
    // New allowed mime types.
    #$mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';
    #$mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['json']  = 'application/json'; 
 
    // Optional. Remove a mime type.
    #unset( $mimes['exe'] );
 
    return $mimes;
}
 
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_custom_mime_types' );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_mimes/